# Find limit $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int\limits_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}f(x){\,dx\over x}$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)\in C[0,1], a>0, b>0$ 
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int\limits_{a\varepsilon}^{b\varepsilon}f(x){\,dx\over x}$$
My attempt: $$\int f(x){\,dx\over x}=\int f(x)\,d(\ln x)=f(x)\ln x - \int\ln x f'(x)dx$$ and I'm stuck here. The answer is $f(0)\ln\frac{b}{a}$ and I see it in the first term, but I don't know what to do with second term in indefinite integral

Comment: Your method is wrong because $f$ is not necessarily derivable.

Comment: No, $f(x)\in C[0,1]$

Comment: Related: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
\left|\int^{b\epsilon}_{a\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(0)}{x}\ dx\right| \leq \int^{b\epsilon}_{a\epsilon}\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{x}\ dx \leq \epsilon(\log b\epsilon-\log a\epsilon) = \epsilon \log\frac{b}{a} \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Your answer doesn't math with the answer from my book

Comment: My answer is exactly the same as the answer you want.

Comment: Does it mean that from your answer I can get that second term is zero? I just can't understand that hint sorry

Comment: That's not really a hint, it's a solution.

Answer (score 2):

*I do not know how much this could help.*

Suppose that function $f(x)$ shows all required properties; expand it as a Taylor series around $x=0$ $$f(x)=f(0)+x f'(0)+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{f(0)}{x}+f'(0)+O\left(x\right)$$ 
$$\int\frac{f(x)}x\,dx=f(0) \log (x)+x f'(0)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Integrate between the bounds
$$\int_{a\epsilon}^{b\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}x\,dx=f(0)\log\left( \frac{ b\epsilon} {a\epsilon}\right)+(b-a)f'(0)\,\epsilon=f(0)\log\left( \frac{ b} {a}\right)+(b-a)f'(0)\,\epsilon$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x=\epsilon y$ to see the integral equals

$$\int_a^b\frac{f(\epsilon y)}{y}\, dy.$$

What does that suggest as $\epsilon\to 0^+?$